# Feasibility of perfectly syncing number counter between app and server?

Tags: android, ios, synchronization

First time asking a question.  I appreciate any thoughts/feedback you may have.

Part of the functionality of an app I am working on requires that an internal counter in the app be in perfect sync with a counter on a remote server.

More specifically, there are 86,400 seconds in a day.  Assume on a server I start a counter that ticks from 1 to 86,400 progressing at one tick a second.  When it gets to 86,400 it starts over at 1.  This then repeats indefinitely.

Part of the functionality of the app is the first time it is launched by the user it will connect to the server and sync a similar running counter within the app to perfectly match the counter on the server.  (e.g.  at the exact same time that the server counter ticks to perhaps 10,215.....so should the app counter be ticking to 10,215.)

Assume perhaps thousands of users have the app.  I need it so that the thousands of individual app users now have 1 - 86,400 counters all running exactly in sync with each other.  With the idea that a user only has to have their app perform this server sync a single time.  After it's synced, the counters within the apps would then run in unison in perpetuity.

Questions:

1) Is this feasible to do?  For the reasons I need this to occur, it literally cannot be off by even a second or two.  They all have to match perfectly.

2) Would varying internet and/or phone speed by user be a problem (during the sync process)?  Again, it is a one time sync.  It does not have to sync on a continuous, real-time basis.  Nonetheless, the first sync does have to be perfect.

3) If the answer to the above is that it is doable.....getting greedy here, can I sync it at even faster speeds?  Instead of the counter just counting up one tick per second (i.e. 86,400 ticks per day), can the counter tick at perhaps a rate of 1/10 of a second (864,000 ticks per day).  At that super fast tick speed, could the perfect sync still be accomplished?

While not the exact reason for needing the above, to give perspective.....imagine I had 100 people sitting in a room download the app.  They then open the app which then all perfectly sync to the server so that they are all now running their individual counters in perfect unison.  At that point, they lose internet connectivity (yet, the counter continues to run within the app in their phone.) If the app was programmed to start playing a particular song when the internal app counter reached tick X, all 100 phones would start playing the song at the exact same time (when their counters in unison reached tick X).

Sorry for the long question, but wanted to lay out my issue.  Thanks everyone!